# Proc Transpose SAS: Transpose and Rename Variables

Tags: sas, rename, transpose

I have a proc transpose question.  The code I have isn't quite giving me what I want.

```
data have;
    input name $ x y z;
cards;
jon 1 85 1300
jon 2 90 2000
jon 3 95 1800
hal 1 70 1500
hal 2 78 4000
hal 3 83 3000
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
    by name;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want;
    by name;
run;
```

I want to end up with a dataset that looks like this:

```
name  y1  y2  y3  z1    z2    z3
hal   70  78  83  1500  4000  3000
jon   85  90  95  1300  2000  1800
```

The main thing here is being able to get one line per name.  Secondary is the ability to use the x variable to rename the others (y1, y2, y3, etc).  I know the first part is probably easy.  Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make it in the form
(by variables) (variable name) (variable value)

In this case that means six rows per person, with `name varname value`.

You can do this easily:

```
data have_pret;
 set have;
 varname=cats('y',x);
 value=y;
 output;
 varname=cats('z',x);
 value=z;
 output;
 keep name value varname;
run;
```

Then you can run proc transpose:

```
proc transpose data=have_pret out=want;
 by name;
 id varname;
 var value;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe-- I found another way to do this, but yours looks more efficient: `data have;
 input name $ x y z;
cards;
jon 1 85 1300
jon 2 90 2000
jon 3 95 1800
hal 1 70 1500
hal 2 78 4000
hal 3 83 3000
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
 by name;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=haveout;
 by name x;
run;

data haveout;
 format _name_ $32.;
 set haveout;
 _name_=strip(x) || "_" || strip(_name_);
run;

proc transpose data=haveout out=want(drop=_name_);
 by name;
 var col1;
run;`